# Bootstrap 4 card deck, vertical align center

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Im Trying to vertically align (center) the the following card deck:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="card-deck d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-xl-2">
          <div class="card d-flex>
             ....
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Currently looks like this:

[image]

I tried with my-auto, align-items-center, justify-content-center... but it doesn't work, what is missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the `container-fluid` have a defined height?

Comment: @Zim no, it doesn't

Comment: **Vertical centering is relative to the height parent**. If the parent has no defined height there is nothing to vertically center. Also, the grid `col-*` are meant to be used in .row, not `card-deck`. https://www.codeply.com/go/4zgVRt6OqJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can vertical align any element using `position: absolute;`

like ,

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">I'm always<br/>In<br>Center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.element {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; 
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.element {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="element">I'm always<br/>In<br>Center</div>
</div>
```

*OR*

using `display: table-cell;`

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">I'm always<br/>In<br>Center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width:200px;
}
```

**LIVE SNIPPET**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">I'm always<br/>In<br>Center</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parent on card-deck, element on col-* and it works! Thank you